# Grafana Table next/previous/number per page possible?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I need help! I also reported this on grafana community. I hope someone has this experience with me here.

I have a table with couple of rows (per day) with LCD gauge cell display mode each columns. As the Dates grows, it will pile up and they will scroll up/down to it. (Refer to screenshot below)

Would it be possible to group it by 7 or 10 per page/view or depending on the value set? And just have the Next/Previous button for other page, and at the same time still has cell display mode applied?

Im looking at the DataTable Panel, but it doesn’t support the cell display mode (like LCD gauge).

Looking forward for some of your answers. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi, What's your Grafana version?

Comment: Hi there. It's Version 7.0.3 (commit: 00ee734baf, branch: HEAD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for confirming the version; so paginations i.e. setting up rows per page was definitely an option in pre v7 table panel but it seems they have dropped the support in v7.

check this link pls -
https://community.grafana.com/t/pagination-in-table-grafana-7-0/31170

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, thank you for directing my to that link. Really appreciate it. Been searching around also for the probable fix but seem that is going nowhere. 
Now, I guess there's no other way, I might go for the DataTable Panel for this. Thanks again.